# Spring Webflux R2DBC: When is EnableR2dbcRepositories required?

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I am learning Spring Webflux. In some code samples they add a `org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.config.EnableR2dbcRepositories` annotation to the main class [[example]](https://vikasverma.tech/post/spring-mysql-r2dbc-example/)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
public class SpringReactiveApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringReactiveApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and in others they don't [[example]](https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/reactive-crud-apis-with-spring-webflux-88509634daa). I have tried it both ways with no difference in the result. So I am trying to understand when do we need this annotation and when we don't?

There is another annotation that I have seen some examples use and other's don't. That is `org.springframework.stereotype.Repository`. In some examples [[e.g.]](https://www.vinsguru.com/spring-data-r2dbc/) I see:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends
        ReactiveCrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
```

others don't use it. so asking same question for this annotation as well.

Answer (score 0):

`@SpringBootApplicaton` is the combination of `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@ComponentScan` and `@Configuration` annotations.

`@EnableAutoConfiguration` enables Spring Boot's auto-configuration mechanism.

By annotating classes/interfaces with `@Repository` annotation we make
clasess/interfaces available for auto-detection during auto-configuration.
Therefore, by default Spring Boot tries to guess the location of `@Repository` definitions as long as the interfaces are located in the same package or sub-package.

But if the repositories are outside of `SpringReactiveApplication` located package we need register repository beans to the context using `@EnableR2dbcRepositories`. We will also get more control by using the `@EnableR2dbcRepositories`.

For the interfaces that extend `ReactiveCrudRepository` it's not necessary to put `@Repository` annotation on them. Because Spring Boot recognizes the repositories by the fact that they extend one of the predefined Repository interfaces.